Exclude records that have 3 or more dates within a series of date columns
I am using phpMyAdmin that uses MySQL version 5.7.
I have a database table called condensed which contains millions of unique emails with multiple "send dates", among other columns.  Some of the emails will have a NULL send date.
Focusing on the just the email and send_date columns here.
Here is an example of the table:
| email  | a_last_sent | b_last_sent | c_last_sent | d_last_sent | ..up to 14 dates
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| email1 | 2024-06-12  | 2024-05-25  |    NULL     | 2024-06-06  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| email2 | 2024-06-01  | 2024-06-16  |  2024-06-05 | 2024-06-19  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| email3 |   NULL      |   NULL      |  2024-05-12 | 2024-06-10  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| email4 |   NULL      | 2024-06-13  |    NULL     | 2024-05-11  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| email5 | 2024-06-09  | 2024-05-01  |    NULL     |    NULL     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------  

I need to exclude anything that has more than 3 sent dates within the month of June.
So if an email has a sent date in 3 or columns within the month of June, do not return those records.
Using my example above, the results should looks something like this:
| email  | a_last_sent | b_last_sent | c_last_sent | d_last_sent | ..up to 14 dates
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| email1 | 2024-06-12  | 2024-05-25  |    NULL     | 2024-06-06  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| email3 |   NULL      |   NULL      |  2024-05-12 | 2024-06-10  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| email4 |   NULL      | 2024-06-13  |    NULL     | 2024-05-11  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| email5 | 2024-06-09  | 2024-05-01  |    NULL     |    NULL     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------  

The results above excluded email2 because it had 4 dates within the month of June.
email1 meets the criteria because it only has 2 dates within the month of June and 1 in May.
email3, email4, and email5 meet the criteria because they only have 1 date within the month of June and 1 in May.
I can write the below query:
SELECT 
  * FROM 
`condensed` 
WHERE 
(
  `a_last_sent` NOT BETWEEN '2024-06-01' AND '2024-06-30'
  OR
  `b_last_sent` NOT BETWEEN '2024-06-01' AND '2024-06-30'
  OR
  `c_last_sent` NOT BETWEEN '2024-06-01' AND '2024-06-30' 
  // remaining date columns     
)

The query above excludes anything within the date range.
So, how can I incorporate the count to exclude anything that has over 3 dates within the specified date range (which in this case is June)?

consdier a case expression with having... sum(when field not between x and y then 1 else 0 end and then a having sum(when field not between x and y then 1 else 0) >=3

The values contains NULLs - so we cannot concat or sum the expressions with the most part of the functions/operators.
I'd recommend you to concat the dates using CONCAT_WS() - this function skips NULLs. Then count the amount of according substrings.
For definite month use something like
SELECT LENGTH(dateslist) - LENGTH(REPLACE(dateslist, '2024-06-', '2024-06')) AS amount, ...
FROM ( SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', a_last_sent, b_last_sent, ..., x_last_sent) AS dateslist, ...
       ...
       )
...

For custom range use UNION, nested REPLACEs (v.5.7 does not support regular expression replace) or register and use according user-defined function.
Of course you may also use multiple COALESCE().
Also you may unpivot your data with multiple UNIONs then count by the common way.

UPDATE

Would you mind providing an example of how the COALESCE or the UNION would work in this case? – John Beasley

Using COALESCE. Edited code from Roemer's answer
...
WHERE 
      (COALESCE(`a_last_sent`, '2000-01-01') BETWEEN '2024-06-01' AND '2024-06-30')
    + (COALESCE(`b_last_sent`, '2000-01-01') BETWEEN '2024-06-01' AND '2024-06-30')
    + (COALESCE(`c_last_sent`, '2000-01-01') BETWEEN '2024-06-01' AND '2024-06-30') 
...

Using UNION:
...
FROM ( SELECT email, a_last_sent FROM table WHERE a_last_sent IS NOT NULL
       UNION ALL
       SELECT email, b_last_sent FROM table WHERE b_last_sent IS NOT NULL
       UNION ALL
       SELECT email, c_last_sent FROM table WHERE c_last_sent IS NOT NULL
       UNION ALL
       ...
       ) AS unpivotted_data
...


Good catch on the NULL.  I would need to see if there are NULL values as well.
Would you mind providing an example of how the COALESCE or the UNION would work in this case?

@JohnBeasley Updated

Use the fact that TRUE counts as 1 when doing maths with it in MySQL.
SELECT * FROM `condensed` 
WHERE 
    (IFNULL(`a_last_sent`, 0) BETWEEN '2024-06-01' AND '2024-06-30')
    + (IFNULL(`b_last_sent`, 0) BETWEEN '2024-06-01' AND '2024-06-30')
    + (IFNULL(`c_last_sent`, 0) BETWEEN '2024-06-01' AND '2024-06-30') 
    // remaining date columns ... BTW bad table structure   
    <= 3; 


Table structure wasn't my idea.  Querying this table is a lot better than the previous, but it wasn't my idea.  I will test your suggestion and revert...

There are NULLs in x_last_sent...

The query seems to be working.  I am not seeing the NULL values though.  I think I should see some.

I added IFNULL's for that, sorry for leaving them out.
